# Is android studio suitable for an app which displays 3d models?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, unity-game-engine, 3d-model

so for my project, I wanted to make an app for android which allows the user to upload 3d models to the cloud(ex: firebase etc.) and then these models can be seen by other users, basically an app for saving 3d models to the cloud, and then displaying it, so is android studio suitable for this, if not please suggest

Comment: Does this answer your question? [3d model viewer in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66741390/3d-model-viewer-in-android-studio)

Comment: @emandt no, I know that you can display 3d models in android studio just wanted to ask if android studio is the best option or not

Comment: I would interpret the question as "can I made a 3d game in Android Studio", and the answer is yes as long as you choose an engine that works well in it (ex: https://libgdx.com/ ) or you're comfortable working in a mixed C++/Java environment (Android Studio has my favorite mixed native/java editing experience). If Java isn't a must have, I might recommend Unity (https://unity.com/) or an engine that works in Xamarin such as MonoGame ( https://www.monogame.net/ ) or Urho3d ( https://urho3d.github.io/ ) if you need native widget support.

Comment: There are also a number of JavaScript frameworks that you could embed in a ReactNative or electron app such as ThreeJS ( https://threejs.org/ ) or BabylonJS ( https://www.babylonjs.com/ ) if Android Studio wasn't a necessity and you wanted the mixed 3d element and native widget experience of something like Xamarin.